# Spring Data missing property error when initialising the SOLR repository

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-solr

I'm relatively new to spring. I'm trying to set up the spring-data-solr package. I'm using this customer class for both the JPA persistence with hibernate, and for writing to SOLR via the SOLR Data adapter. It hasn't worked yet.

```
When I start the server I get this error in the log:

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private com.ideafactory.mvc.customers.model.CustomerRepository com.ideafactory.mvc.customers.admin.AddressController.customerRepository; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property flush found for type Customer!
```

Originally, it was saying no property "save" found on customer, so I did a test and just added a property called save. Then if I add flush, it says no property "delete" found. But it doesn't seem right to just keep adding these properties onto my domain class. I seem to be missing something on this Customer class to support the SOLR repository (maybe).

Also if I disable the @EnableSOLRRepositories annotation on my configuration class, the error doesn't happen, so it's definitely a problem related to the SOLR repository configuration.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

The class is below:

```
package com.ideafactory.mvc.customers.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


@Entity(name = "customer")
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String preferredName;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Basic
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @Basic
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String bio;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String website;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Date lastLogin;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Date lastLogout;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CustomerStatus status;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date lastModified;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private boolean requiresReset;

    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private boolean subscriber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    @Basic
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Address> addressBook;




    public String getPreferredName() {
        return preferredName;
    }

    public void setPreferredName(String preferredName) {
        this.preferredName = preferredName;
    }

    public boolean isSubscriber() {
        return subscriber;
    }

    public void setSubscriber(boolean subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
    }

    public boolean isRequiresReset() {
        return requiresReset;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getLastModified() {
        return lastModified;
    }

    public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
        this.lastModified = lastModified;
    }

    public boolean getRequiresReset() {
        return requiresReset;
    }

    public void setRequiresReset(boolean requiresReset) {
        this.requiresReset = requiresReset;
    }



    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="customer_roles",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="customerId", referencedColumnName="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="roleId", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private List<Role> roles;

    @Transient
    public boolean isPersisted() {
        return (this.id != null);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String name) {
        this.firstName = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }




    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Role> userRoles = this.getRoles();
        if(userRoles != null)
        {
            for (Role role : userRoles) {
                SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName());
                authorities.add(authority);
            }
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername()
    {
        return getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }


    @PrePersist
    void createdAt() {
        this.createdAt = this.lastModified = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void updatedAt() {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    public void setBio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public Date getLastLogin() {
        return lastLogin;
    }

    public void setLastLogin(Date lastLogin) {
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }

    public Date getLastLogout() {
        return lastLogout;
    }

    public void setLastLogout(Date lastLogout) {
        this.lastLogout = lastLogout;
    }

    public CustomerStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(CustomerStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddressBook() {
        return addressBook;
    }

    public void setAddressBook(List<Address> addressBook) {
        this.addressBook = addressBook;
    }
}
```

This was all I had for the eCustomer Repository. Am I supposed to implement an extension class?

```
package com.ideafactory.mvc.customers.model;

import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.SolrCrudRepository;

/**
 * This is the SOLR repository handler
 */
public interface CustomerSolrCrudRepositoryImpl extends SolrCrudRepository<Customer, String> {
}
```

**************** Update Below *******************

I've narrowed the problem down a little. I downloaded the source code for the spring jpa and stuck a debug point on the SolrRepositoryFactory class. So this is bizarre, but it's trying to resolve the named queries from my hibernate JPA repository using SOLR. So at the point the exception happens, it's trying to initialise what looks like a named query against SOLR. In my CustomerRepository (the Hibernate one) I've got findByEmail(String email).

What am I missing here? Why would the Solr repository initialisation be doing anything with my Hibernate customer repository definition?

```
/**
 * Created on 30/06/2014.
 */

public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    public List<Customer> findByEmail(String emailAddress);

    public Address findOneByAddressBookId(Long addressId);

}
```

SOLR Config:

```
/**
 * This class initialises the SOLR repositories.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(value = "com.ideafactory", multicoreSupport = true)
public class SolrConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_SOLR_SERVER_URL = "solr.server.url";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public SolrServerFactory solrServerFactory() {
        return new MulticoreSolrServerFactory(new HttpSolrServer(
                environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_SOLR_SERVER_URL)));
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrOperations solrTemplate1() {
        SolrTemplate solrTemplate = new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactory());
        solrTemplate.setSolrCore("core1");
        return solrTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrOperations solrTemplate2() {
        SolrTemplate solrTemplate = new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactory());
        solrTemplate.setSolrCore("core2");
        return solrTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrServer solrServer() throws MalformedURLException, IllegalStateException {
        return new HttpSolrServer(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_SOLR_SERVER_URL));
    }
}
```

The stack trace follows.

```
17:34:39.966 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader 318 initWebApplicationContext - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ideafactory.mvc.customers.model.CustomerRepository com.ideafactory.mvc.customers.admin.AddressController.customerRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[AbstractBeanFactory$1.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[AbstractApplicationContext.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[AbstractApplicationContext.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381) ~[ContextLoader.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293) [ContextLoader.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [ContextLoaderListener.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4758) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1588) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
28-Jul-2014 17:34:39.975 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
28-Jul-2014 17:34:39.976 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [?:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ideafactory.mvc.customers.model.CustomerRepository com.ideafactory.mvc.customers.admin.AddressController.customerRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[InjectionMetadata.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[AbstractBeanFactory$1.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[InjectionMetadata.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 56 more
28-Jul-2014 17:34:39.980 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[Part.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:213) ~[PartTree$OrPart.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:321) ~[PartTree$Predicate.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:301) ~[PartTree$Predicate.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:82) ~[PartTree.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.PartTreeSolrQuery.<init>(PartTreeSolrQuery.java:36) ~[PartTreeSolrQuery.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactory$SolrQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(SolrRepositoryFactory.java:130) ~[SolrRepositoryFactory$SolrQueryLookupStrategy.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:320) ~[RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:169) ~[RepositoryFactorySupport.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224) ~[RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210) ~[RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.java:66) ~[SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.class:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[AbstractBeanFactory$1.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[InjectionMetadata.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: could you provide the whole exception stacktrace?

Comment: I just posted an edit with the stacktrace and some more info I figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for reference in case anyone needs it. I don't think I've quite fixed it, or understand why it was happening. But I've worked around this by separating the JPA repositories and SOLR repositories into separate packages, and in the annotation for each explicitly setting the full package directory.

I guess it could just be me not understanding how the repository initialisers work in Spring. So I just changed it to these values and it seems to have at least resolved the first issue:

e.g

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.ideafactory.mvc.repositories.jpa")

@EnableSolrRepositories(value = "com.ideafactory.mvc.repositories.solr", multicoreSupport = true)